# Using Cassandra and MySQL together with JPA in Play framework

Tags: jpa, playframework, cassandra, hector, kundera

**I would like to use Cassandra NoSQL server with an RDBMS in Play 2.3.0!**

Started to build it up using Kundera, according to this tutorial:

http://recipes4geeks.com/2013/07/06/play-nosql-building-nosql-applications-with-play-framework/

It works fine, and I can use it with pure mysql-jdbc connection, and it also works if I use jdbc for Cassandra connection and JPA for MySQL..
.. but the goal is to use a persistence framework, without handling basic JDBC stuffs!

It looks, this problem was mentioned in the link above:

> Caution: javaJdbc app dependency downloads hibernate-entitymanager jar file that interferes with Kundera. Make sure you remove this app dependency which is by default present.

- If I remove the hibernate-entitymanager from the dependencies, the project runs, but when it wants to call the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql") method, Play says: *No Persistence provider...* as it was expected.
- If I keep the hibernate-entitymanager in the dependencies list, beside the kundera client, the Play server simply shuts down.

Is there a possibility to make it work or I have to replace Kundera?

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus JPA supports persistence to all RDBMS around (via JDBC), as well as to Cassandra, MongoDB, Neo4j, LDAP, HBase and many others. It's Cassandra support seems to be for all latest versions and uses the native Cassandra driver (not JDBC) and so no chance of conflicts like above. You can read up on it at

http://www.datanucleus.org

Answer (score 0):

Caution: javaJdbc app dependency downloads hibernate-entitymanager jar file that interferes with Kundera. Make sure you remove this app dependency which is by default present.

This should not be an issue with latest Kundera releases.  Also you can email sample project at kundera@impetus.co.in in case looking for quick support.